# Autodesk Viewer Error: TranslationWorker-InternalFailure Extractor error code -1073741819

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I tried to upload a 450MB stp file to Autodesk Viewer
https://viewer.autodesk.com/designviews

However, it caused an error saying "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure Extractor error code -1073741819"

I can display the stp file on Fusion360.
How can I solve this issue?
Thank you.